# Get Default Background Colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to fetch the colour of my Submit buttons background-colour on click using JQuery however when doing so the hover colour is stored instead of the default.

```
var originalCol = rgb2hex($("#submit").css('backgroundColor'));
```

How can I modify the above code to get me the default background colour rather than the hover colour?

Comment: You can only get the `background-color` that is currently applied to the element. Note that what you describe can be achieved in CSS alone, without the need for any JS at all.

Comment: Can you include `css`, `html` at Question? Is `css` `:hover` or `javascript` `onmouseover` event used to change background color?

Comment: When you click on your submit button your technically hovering over it. So if you have a hover backgroundcolor css attribute set and you click on the submit button, it will set the buttons current bg color to that value before you click the button and return the hover value.  Save the bg color before you click the button and then just return that value.

Comment: Feel a bit stupid now but I will just store the value on page load

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the backgroundColor BEFORE you hover over the element. Obviously the hovered button has different backgroundColor.

The `$(element).css()` accesses the computed value.

So you should read the bgColor at the same time as when you attach the event listener.

Comment: Oh yeah I think I will make it just store on page load then. I feel a bit stupid now